# Unit testing against Nancy.Request.Session

Tags: unit-testing, nancy

I am probably missing something simple here....

I have the following method I want to unit test:

```cs
public bool In(Request request)
{
    return ("Admin" == (string)request.Session["Type"]);
}
```

This proved less easy than I expected, because I can't find a way to properly set up a `Request` object to pass to the method.
Directly newing up a `Request` results in an object that is not session enabled, and my crude attempts with a makeshift `ConfigurableBootstrapper` implementation and module were quite unsuccessful.

(I found [this blog post](http://blog.csainty.com/2012/05/enabling-sessions-in-nancy.html), but with no code to illustrate the explanation, I can't make much of it; I could also find no actual examples in the AppHarbify code.)

So, what would be the easiest/recommended way to get a `Request` object on which I can use `Session`?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using Claims for verifying if a user is an Admin or now.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that wraps the Request. Something like..

```
public interface IRequestWrapper {
    Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

The pass this interface instead of the actual implementation to the "In" method.

```
    public bool In(IRequestWrapper request)
    {
        return ("Admin" == (string)request.Session["Type"]);
    }
```

Now in your Unit Test you would create a fake implementation of IRequestWrapper that returns a Fake Session objtect?

```
        var sut = new SomeClass();

        var result = sut.In(new FakeRequest());
```

Of course the FakeRequest would implement IRequestWrapper and the Session object can be stubbed to return "Admin".

There are other ways to do this, for example, using a Mock/Isolation frameworks, i.e Moq

Hope this helps at least put you in the right direction.